# page not redirecting in controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

This my link

```
  <li class="active"><a href="/createform">Create Form</a></li>
```

this is my controller

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/createform")
public String createform(Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    //some other codes
return "form";
}
```

and this is my `view.xml`

```
<definition name="form"  extends="default">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/jsps/tags/Form.jsp" />
    </definition>
```

My problem is Form.jsp is not opening.When hit the link the URL changes to `localhost:8080/pro/createform' but the contents of Form.jsp is not opening instead I am getting only one word "form".

When I debug then I can see the control is going to controller but the contents of Form.jsp is not opening

Can any body tell me the reason?

Comment: Try to remove the @ResponseBody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/createform")
public String createform(Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //some other codes
    return "form";
}
```

The problem is your code (above). You have annotated the method with `@ResponseBody` which, as the annotation name implies, will return the result as the body of the response. However you want to have a view and use a `ViewResolver` to select the correct view.

To fix this simply remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation.

```
@RequestMapping("/createform")
public String createform(Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //some other codes
    return "form";
}
```

**Links**

1. @ResponseBody | [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html)
2. @RequestMapping | [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your problem

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/createform")
    public ModalAndView createform(Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        //some other codes
    return new ModalAndView("Form");
    }
```